# Is there a name for a tree with all leaf vertices identified with each other?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, trees

Is there a name for those graphs that can be formed by taking a tree and identifying all the vertices of degree 1 (leaves) with each other?

Or, if I understand correctly, an equivalent definition may be: Those graphs that can be formed by taking a tree, and then adding a vertex that shares an edge with all vertices of degree 1.

Comment: Are you asking about finite graphs? In the finite case all these graphs have connectivity $\kappa(G)=2$, but ne converse is not true. The second definition is not the same as the first because you cannot obtain the graphs you would get in the first one when you start from a tree with two or three vertices.

Comment: In a paper of mine with Alan Sokal (https://arxiv.org/abs/1307.1721), graphs of this type were important and because we could not find a name for them at the time, we used the term "leaf-joined tree" to refer to a graph formed from a particular tree (in our case a complete k-ary tree of certain depth) by identifying all the vertices.

Comment: Thanks @m-winter for pointing out that the definitions are not equivalent. I am interested in whether either class of graphs has a known name. (Yes, finite case.)